# sign of derivative at zero of a continuous and differentiable function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I think this is straightforward but I cannot prove it with my rusty calculus...

Suppose $f(x)$ is a continuous and differentiable functionon on $[a,b]$, $f(a)>0$, and $f(b)<0$.

I want to show that there exists $c\in [a,b]$ such that $f'(c)\leq 0$ and $f(c)=0$.

Any suggestions? Or a counter-example? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have a continuous function on a compact interval, so it is $0$ only finitely many times. A reasonable choice of $c$ might be the largest $x$ such that $f(x) = 0$.

Now there are two possibilities. If $f'(c) \leq 0$, then you're done.

If $f'(c) > 0$, then $f(x)$ is increasing in a neighborhood of $c$, and most importantly there is some $d > c$ such that $f(d) > 0$. But as $f$ is continuous, there would be another $x$ with $x > d$ such that $f(x) = 0$, contradicting the maximality of $c$.

Thus $f(c) = 0$ and $f'(c) \leq 0$. $\diamondsuit$

This is not the only way, but it's short and intuitive, I think. Notice also that the condition that $f'(c) \leq 0$ is necessary, as there are functions that are strictly decreasing, $0$ only once, but whose derivative at that $0$ is $0$. For example, if you stitch a bump function to another (upside-down) bump function, you get one such example.

Comment: Thanks. I think this is almost the proof. But I don't see why a continuous function on a compact interval can only hit 0 for finitely many times. But if there are an infinite number of zeros, one can think about $\sup{c|f(c)=0,f'(c)>0}$. If it equals $b$, then the function is not continuous at $b$; if it is less than $b$, then one can find $x$ between $\sup{c|f(c)=0,f'(c)>0}$ and $b$ and we will have a contradiction.